# How to check which columns are required for a database insert statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, metadata

I am trying to insert into a table like any old Insert statement. This is not a problem, but the table has a few columns to the tune of about 20. As such I wanted to ask a quick question. How can you check which columns are required and which are auto generated by the system or default to NULL. By knowing I could take some large table insert like below:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (A1,B2,C3,D4... to Z1000) 
VALUES (1,2,3,4,... to x);
```

Then I could simplify it to the bare minimumn for an insert + key parameters needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for NOT NULL constraints, you could query `ALL_TAB_COLS` for `NULLABLE`:

For example, below query will show all columns which are nullable. Similarly, you could filter as `NULLABLE = 'N'` to get the columns which are not null.

```
SELECT column_name
  FROM all_tab_cols
 WHERE owner = 'HR'
   AND table_name = 'EMPLOYEES'
   AND NULLABLE ='Y';

COLUMN_NAME    
---------------
FIRST_NAME
PHONE_NUMBER
SALARY
COMMISSION_PCT
MANAGER_ID
DEPARTMENT_ID

6 rows selected.
```

For auto generated `IDENTITY` columns, you could query `ALL_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS`.

```
SELECT column_name,
       generation_type,
       identity_options
FROM   all_tab_identity_cols
WHERE  owner = 'OWNER'
AND table_name = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

To quickly refer an object description, you could also use the SQL Plus `DESCRIBE` command. It will also run on most of the tools which support sqlplus commands like SQL Developer etc.

Comment: Also, the "DESC table" is useful. The above tables were useful for quickly viewing that specific information or lack of.

Comment: `DESC` is a SQL Plus command, which would be useful too, to quickly verify it. But the views I have demonstrated would help to generate reports etc. Also, you cannot use SQL Plus commands in PL/SQL.